# Using the Ellipsis at the End of a Page

Tags: punctuation, ellipses

I am writing an Introductory page for my book. Being that it is the last sentence on the page, would it be OK to say, "Let's get on with the story... " or would I write "Let's get on with the story."? And while I am at it: Are the punctuations in this question placed where they should be? Does it look like I need to brush up on my punctuations?

Comment: You cannot say "punctuations" in English. And ellipses are used incorrectly in etxtmsgz.

Comment: Of course you can write *punctuations*. It's just nonstandard. That aside, you could even write *Let's get on with the story?* if you were asking a question, *Let's get on with the story!* if you were being forceful, or *Let's get on with the story—* if you were being interrupted (rather than trailing off). The punctuation you use represents what you're trying to communicate. There is nothing wrong with using periods or ellipses. They just communicate different things.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using ellipsis in the context described.  Yes, there are those who might get Pist, but you are clearly writing in an informal style.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking what your reader will think if you violate a convention of punctuation.

One of the truly great writers of the 20th century, Samuel Beckett, began his novel, *Murphy* as follows:-

> The sun was shining, having no alternative, on the nothing new.

This is a far greater violation of convention than yours.  It shocks the reader with something grammatically unexpected.  Instead of “... the glittering water” or “... sleepy rooftops”, we get brought down with a crash to a mundane world:  “...the nothing new”.  In your case, it is obvious what the three dots are for.

Comment: An upvote for seeing that punctuation in this context is convention: it has nothing to do with meaning.